# Troubleshoot Azure Inbound Security Rule

Tags: security, azure, website

I have a node.js app running on an Ubuntu server. I was able to `-X SSH` in and check that it was running properly with firefox on localhost:4000.

I then add a new inbound security rule from the Azure portal.

The site still isn't accessible from outside the server. I run the following from my desktop:

```
telnet 104.99.99.99 4000
```

And I get connection timed out.

Results from `sudo iptables -L`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

**Security rule:**

[image]

Comment: Did you check your server-level firewall rules?

Comment: Would 'sudo iptables -L' be what I want for checking those rules?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly right. Edit your question and post the output of that command in proper code blocks, please.

Comment: You show iptables, but you don't show your inbound security rules. Please edit your question to show how you configured inbound rules on your network security group.

Comment: I added a screen shot of the security rule I added via the azure portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 things come to my mind:

- your application listening on localhost:4000 which is not your network interface IP hence despite correct Azure firewall settings it's still not reachable from anywhere else than a server itself. Check `netstat -anep | grep -w 4000` and make sure it's listening either on 0.0.0.0 or IP of the network interface that you use (be it eth0 or anything else). If it's listening on 127.0.0.1, then it's not going to be reachable from outside world
- outgoing traffic from your server:4000 is blocked by Azure firewall. Quite unlikely but try to create another firewall rule to allow your server's outgoing traffic from port 4000 to be 100% sure it's not a blocker
- additional iptables filters in place not visible with just `iptables -L`. To display them all, use: `iptables -vL -t filter`, `iptables -vL -t nat`, `iptables -vL -t mangle`, `iptables -vL -t raw`, `iptables -vL -t security`

Answer (score 1):

You have mentioned NodeJS is listening on localhost:4000.

That means it is only reachable from inside your own server. The NodeJS service has to be listening on 0.0.0.0:4000 (for any interface) or your.private.ip.address:4000 for a specific interface, e.g.:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(4000, "0.0.0.0");
console.log('Server running at http://0.0.0.0:4000/');
```

The above snippet will start the server on 0.0.0.0:4000, so you can reach it from outside on 104.99.99.99:4000 or whatever public IP address you have.

Comment: Tried changing it but I get the same result. Also I created a new centos vm and I can access the site on port 4000 fine. Must be some kind of weird glitch.